# Why the property's value I get from application.properties file always null on spring boot?

Tags: spring-boot

The property's value always null when I read from application.properties on spring boot.

---

application.properties

> app.myProperty=1234

class AppProperties:

```
@Component
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "app")
public class AppProperties {

    private String myProperty;

    public String getMyProperty() {
        return myProperty;
    }

    public void setMyProperty(String myProperty) {
        this.myProperty = myProperty;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
@RestController
@Slf4j
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    AppProperties appProperties;

    @PostMapping(RoutePath.TEST)
    public ResultVO test() {

        try {

            log.info("property value:" + appProperties.getMyProperty());

            return ResultVOUtil.success(null);

       } catch (Exception ex) {

            return ResultVOUtil.error(CommonUtil.logExceptionError("发生错误。", null, ex));
        }
    }

}
```

log output:

> property value:null